# Is it possible to show shared site rendering variant at the top of variant drop down?

Tags: sxa

Is it possible to show shared site rendering variant at the top of variant drop down?

Currently, We have rendering variant in shared site and actual site and it is showing actual site rendering variant at the top after that shared site rendering variant. We would like to show shared site rendering variant at the top of dropdown?

Answer (score 3):

There is a pipeline called `getVariants`. It's responsible for creating the list of available variants. You would need to rearrange processors there:

```
<getVariants>
    <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites.Pipelines.GetVariants.SwitchPageTemplateId, Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites" resolve="true"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.GetVariants.GetSystemVariants, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions" resolve="true"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.GetVariants.GetSiteVariants, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions" resolve="true"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.GetVariants.GetLinkedVariants, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions" resolve="true"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.GetVariants.GetSharedVariants, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions" resolve="true"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.GetVariants.FilterVariants, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions" resolve="true"/>
</getVariants>
```

`GetSharedVariants` should be before `GetSiteVariants` processor.

Patch file like this should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"
               xmlns:env="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/env/"
               xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <getVariants>
        <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.GetVariants.GetSharedVariants, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions">
          <patch:delete />
        </processor>
        <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.GetVariants.GetSharedVariants, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions"
          resolve="true"
          patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.GetVariants.GetSiteVariants, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions']" />
      </getVariants>

    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```